# Возможно ли развернуть свой DNS over HTTPS сервер и будет ли он работать в случае отключения DNS в стране?

Tags: dns

Или же локально можно где то записать IP адреса популярных сайтов например того Яндекса и ходить по IP в такой ситуации?? Например обращать к Yandex по IP 77.88.21.3

Comment: Так Яндекс в любом случае будет работать, он же российский

Comment: А записать всегда можно в системный файл hosts

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно. Например, на базе HTTP/2 сервера H2O.
[Свой DNS-over-HTTPS сервер на базе веб-сервера H2O](https://kostikov.co/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-dns-over-https-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-h2o)